# Can we now mock static methods with Mockito 2?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I read that Mockito 2 doesn't use CGLIB/proxy any more but instead uses ByteBuddy for mock creation. Does that mean that from now on it is possible to mock static methods and private methods?

Comment: Mockito developers haven't added support for mocking of `static` methods *yet*, but they probably will in future versions. After all, it can be done basically in the same way that `final` mocking was already done.

Comment: *pulls out popcorn* and watches eagerly.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't (see their documentation [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html); I am sure they would mention that).

So, PowerMock(ito) and JMockit are the two mocking frameworks that support mocking static methods.

But, some personal opinion: one should nonetheless prefer to use Mockito instead PowerMock(ito); simply by writing code that can be tested with Mockito; and that doesn't need PowerMock. What I mean is: when you write your *own* code and you think you *need* to mock static calls; then you are writing *hard to test* code.

The answer is not to look to powerful mocking frameworks; but to write *easy to test* code instead. You can have a look into these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to learn how to do that.

Finally: don't think that PowerMockito is a good alternative. Mockito is right now at version 2.79 (as of March 2017). But when you have a look at PowerMockito; you will find that it ships with some Mockito 2.0.42 beta something - because the PowerMockito folks can't get their tool working with any newer version of Mockito. And that is a shame, because those newer Mockito versions have a lot of interesting features.

Comment: Seriously, this answer is so grossly wrong! Mockito [added `final` mocking](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final) as an optional feature. It uses a *Java agent* (actually, the `java.lang.instrument` API), which is the same fundamental mechanism used by JMockit, the *other* mocking library which supports mocking statics, etc., which you know about but "forgot" to mention. PowerMock never was the only one, as JMockit has been doing it all since 2006. Finally, it's only a matter of time until Mockito adds `static` mocking.

Comment: Just to clarify to other readers: I developed JMockit, and I have in a few previous occasions commented to @GhostCat about it. So, it's a shame that he chooses to deliberately lie about PowerMock being (according to him) the only mocking library without restrictions. In addition to that, he also repeatedly (see his other answers in SO) tries to put PowerMock down - PowerMock may have its problems but it does not deserve this.

Comment: Which part of this answer is a lie? And yes, you write those comments. But just for the record: how often did you write answers that contradict my statements by showing a solution to that powermock problem? What I keep saying is that powermock comes at certain *cost*, and that cost is in certain regards higher than those of other frameworks. Meaning: you would be free to give a better answer each and any time you critique my answers. But you don't. And in the context of this question ; does your framework allow to mock static? If not, why is that?

Comment: @Rogério Anyway ... if you are interested in, we could agree on some date and sit down and chat a while. I guess you have good reasons and experience and that makes you defend PowerMock; but I have made a lot of experience in using that tool; and it simply has cost me (and the teams around me) more time then we ever got out of its "unique selling points". So, when you are interested in more than dropping that "GhostCat is a liar" comments ... drop me a comment; and lets see if we can chat ...

Comment: @Rogério I overlooked your first comment and improved my answer regarding that aspect. And yes, you write your comments. But just for the record: how often did you write answers that contradict my statements by showing a solution to some powermock problem? What I keep saying is that powermock comes at certain cost, and that cost is in certain regards higher than those of other frameworks. You would be free to give a better answer each and any time you critique my answers. But you don't ...

Comment: The lie was the part saying that PowerMock is the *only* mocking library that supports mocking statics (I pointed this out in my first two comments). This part has been edited out now in the answer, of course.

Comment: "does your framework allow to mock static?" Huh?!? You apparently don't read my comments, because I am sure I said that JMockit does mock statics (etc.) several times already.

Comment: "how often did you write answers that contradict my statements by showing a solution to some powermock problem?" From what I remember, you only bash PowerMock, without describing specific problems. But explain how to avoid/solve specific problems with PowerMock was never my goal; the best "solution" to those would be use JMockit, *when* insisting in mocking something. But really, I don't care if you (or anybody) use JMockit or not - the point I care about is to stop all this misinformation about mocking libraries, and about the value of the idea of mocking itself (personally, I rarely use it).

Comment: Finally, about the claim that "when you write your own code and you think you need to mock static calls; then you are writing hard to test code." I disagree in two ways: 1) if someone thinks to mock something (whether static or not), they are already in the way to a bad test; 2) assuming that mocking is acceptable in a given situation, if what needs to be mocked happens to be a `static` method then it's no better or worse than mocking anything else (for example, mocking JSF's `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` in order to check an expected `addMessage(...)` call is perfectly reasonable).

Comment: Lets go one by one: the information that JMockit supporst static mocking, too ... never made it up to my higher brain regions. I apologize for that; and rest assured; I wont "lie" about that again. But then: I am doing intensive unit tests more than 5 years by now. Initially we started of with PowerMock. We mocked static stuff. And there were many many occasions when a PowerMocked test suddenly failed - without the direct class under test being changed. But some static thing somewhere else, related to that class changed. And I think I already mentioned that ...

Comment: just go and have a look into the powermock tagged questions here. You will find several that describe really bizarre problems. I am not alone there. And for the record: after we had that discussion some days ago; I turned to the slack channel on the "java specialist" site ... quick random survey: everybody there rejected the idea of *static* mocking. In the sense of: there are shades of grey. Of course, ideally, you write code that can be tested without any mocking. But there are many occasions were that is not possible. But then there are some nice, *simple* "non intrusive" ...

Comment: ways to get that tested. But *static* stuff is on a different scale. If your static code can't be tested without mocking, and you also have a **very** hard time later on. Because you created code that is glued together in a very tight manner. And again, when I spoke to the folks java specialist, I got the feeling that people were mainly in agreement. To quote one about "static mocking" resp. powermock: *forcing obscure error situations is probably the only valid use case*.

Comment: @Rogério So, long story short: A) I think there are different levels of "evilness" of mocking, and "static mocking" is at least one order of magnitude worse than "ordinary" mocking B) many people simply do not understand that part. They think *whatever* problem they have with their production code, the answer is to be found in mocking frameworks. I have seen with my own eyes that certain mocking frameworks *can* cause a lot of trouble in the long run. But I think since our last exchange I already try to contain myself in that regard.Hope we can settle that now ...

Answer (score -2):

I wrote [an extension](https://github.com/iirekm/varia/tree/develop/ajmock) of `Mockito 2` which uses `AspectJ` to `allow mocking` even things like `static/private/final methods`, with one easy lambda-based syntax, for example:

`when(() -> YourClass.staticMethodToCall(...)).thenReturn(...)`

Comment: The [ajmock GitHub repository](https://github.com/iirekm/misc/tree/master/ajmock) of this `Mockito 2` extension is no longer available and it seems that it has been deleted because I didn't find it elsewhere as a moved/renamed/cloned repository.

Comment: The repository is not available anymore.

Comment: yep. The repo seems to have vanished, can you post an updated location?

Comment: I fixed the broken link